# Prevent PDF downloading but allow read on IIS 8

Tags: iis

Is it posible to prevent direct PDF file downloading but allow read trought iframe or another method?

Denying file extension on Reques Filtering on IIS 8 will also prevent read the PDF file on an iframe. Is there a way to prevent direct download but allow read?

Comment: How are you presenting your PDF file? There are many ways to block the download of pdf, you need to know how to block the download according to your usage. about allowing the use of pdf files in iis, you can enable it in the MIME Map section.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the question as uncoded NO the format of a PDF is a bitstream of mixed encodings and "relative" decimal addresses, that needs decompiling ONCE it has an "absolute" download filename.

Thus to view the text on a display or paper it needs to be decoded in the device that can render the full file stream contents using a CPU (there are means to dribble a modified 2way transport but not cheap on resources). That can be a print server or printer or a users pdf viewer in or outwith the html editor we call a browser.

Therefor the PORT in PDF means it needs transPORT to the device. In the Public Domain That's done by Hyper TEXT TransPORT. We call that a Download or Upload (depending which end point you are).

Once the data is received in the viewer / editor it can be converted into screen pixels.